# How to get a column matrix for words written in Devanagari?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am a latex novice and I am trying to get something like the figure below except that i want to use Hindi words in place.

Preamble for creating the figure below

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
square\\
\\
ball\\
\\
box\\
\end{array}
\right]
\rightarrow
is\\
\end{array}
\right]
\rightarrow
big\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

For Hindi words I am trying

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
%\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Hindi}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Hindi}
\begin{document}
\left[
\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{चौकोर} \\
\right]
\end{document}
```

but I am getting an empty square bracket.

I understand that `\left.` and `\right.` is used in maths mode. Is there any other alternative to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an environment that typesets the entries in text mode, but then adds brackets:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Devanagari MT} % <-- I don't have Lohit Hindi

\newenvironment{textmatrix}
 {$\left[\begin{tabular}{c}}
 {\end{tabular}\right]$}

\newcommand\textarrow{${}\rightarrow{}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{textmatrix}
  \begin{textmatrix}
  \textsanskrit{चौकोर} \\
  \textsanskrit{चौकोर} \\
  \textsanskrit{चौकोर}
  \end{textmatrix}
  \textarrow\textsanskrit{चौकोर}
\end{textmatrix}\textarrow\textsanskrit{चौकोर}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use `amsmath` and its macro `\text` or as an alternative the macro `\mbox`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
%\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Hindi}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} 
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{lohit_hi.ttf}
\newcommand\textSK[1]{\text{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{\devanagarifont#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
 \textSK{चौकोर} \\
foo\\
\mbox{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{\devanagarifont चौकोर}}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
foo \textSK{चौकोर}
\end{document}
```

[image]